# JSP page variable values changes per request

Tags: java, jsp

The below jsp code is not giving output as expected

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" buffer="none" autoFlush="true"%>
<%@page import="java.util.logging.Logger" %>


<%!  
    String test = "Hei you!!!"; 
    String test2="ok done"; 
%>  <%= test = (test + test2)%>
```

**out put: (on sbusequent page refresh)**

```
Hei you!!! ok done
Hei you!!! ok done
Hei you!!! ok done
```

**expecting:(only on each request)**

```
Hei you!!! ok done
```

I am not sure if the variable 'test' is stored in cache in jsp server or any binding occurs or variable in this case is stored in application/session scope.
Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 3):

`<%!  %>` is declaration section which means

```
String test = "Hei you!!!"; 
String test2="ok done";
```

will be fields in generated from jsp servlet, not local variables in `jspService()` method so each time you do

```
<%= test = (test + test2)%>
```

`text` field will be concatenated with value from `test2`.

---

In other words your code will generate code similar to

```
public class Problem extends SomeSpecialJSPHttpServlet {

    String test = "Hei you!!!"; 
    String test2 = "ok done"; 

    protected void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().print(test = (test + test2));
    }
}
```

---

To print only `test + test2` don't reassign this result to `test` so maybe just use

```
<%= test + test2 %>
```

Comment: [Here's a reference.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks.But then how can we declare fields in jspService?

Comment: @master32 Get rid of `!`. Use `<%  %>`, or even better [avoid putting Java code in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<%=(test + test2)%>
```

Comment: Thanks Ayshman.But I am not trying to solve it but know the reason